# How to set max width for specific block with TinyMCE editor

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I've integrated TinyMCE with React.js.

But there is a feature I need which seems TinyMCE doesn't support it natively so I wanna know how can I add it.

you see the two blocks that are surrounded by the red box (see the image below) have `maxWidth` and `width` which I set it manually via DevTools

```css
max-width: 800px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
```

**I wanna know how can I set the above css for the current selected block using TinyMCE API.**

so the user can resize the `max-width` for the current selected block by clicking a button in the toolbar (which will call the TinyMCE API to resize its `max-width`)

[image]